# format text inside drop down box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to get a code and the full name of an attribute formatted and displayed in a drop down box. I already have the code to get the two values displayed but they are not formatted. The problem is that not all characters will consume the same amount of space. The code can contain numbers or letters.

```
render : function() {
            this.$el.attr('value', this.model.get('ptTimeCd')).html(
                this.model.get('ptTimeCd') + "&nbsp&nbsp|&nbsp"
                + this.model.get('ptTimeName'));

            return this;
        }
```

This produces a drop down with something like the following:

A1  | some text
CM   | some more text
GB  | ...

is there a way I can make all of this align so that the vertical will always be in the same place?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are having a problem with the nature of [variable width, or "proportional" fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion). What you'll need is a [monospaced](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html) font/font-family instead.

Perhaps try something like this css rule:

```
.mono {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, Fixed, monospace;
}
```

Then apply the css class to your drop-down list items and see if you get something more like what you want to achieve.

Then you just need to make sure each 'section' of your item has the same amount of characters and spaces, which is a relatively simple programming logic exercise where you pad or trim each section based upon the string length. Just ask again if you need help with that specific portion.